# Skip specific rows using LAG in sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, lag, skip

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

Using the LAG function in SQL, I would like to perform the LAG on only values where star_date=end_date and  get the past previous start_date record where start_date=end_date.
That my end table will have an extra column like this:
[image]

I hope my question is clear, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign a group to these values and use that:

```
select t.*,
       (case when start_date = end_date
             then lag(start_date) over (partition by (case when start_date = end_date then 1 else 0 end) order by start_date)
        end) as prev_eq_start_date
from t;
```

Or:

```
select t.*,
       (case when start_date = end_date
             then lag(start_date) over (partition by start_date = end_date order by start_date)
        end) as prev_eq_start_date
from t;
```

Note if you data is big and most rows have different dates, then you might have a resources issue.  In this case, an additional, unused `partition by` key can help:

```
select t.*,
       (case when start_date = end_date
             then lag(start_date) over (partition by (case when start_date = end_date then 1 else 2 end), (case when start_date <> end_date then start_date end) order by start_date)
        end) as prev_eq_start_date
from t;
```

This has no impact on the result but it can avoid a resources error caused by too many rows with different values.

Comment: I believe `partition by (StartDate = EndDate)` will give syntax error !

Comment: @VigneshKumarA . . . I've gotten so used to using `countif()` that I forgot that BQ does not treat booleans equal to other types.

Comment: I thought `partition by (StartDate = EndDate)` would perfectly worked! have you tested and confirmed that it did not?!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant . . . In fact, I did test it and it generated an error.  Of course, I might have gotten the test wrong.  I didn't press the issue.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - just tested your original answer (with `partition by (start_date = end_date)`) and it works perfectly for me (BigQuery Standard SQL) - I think it is elegant enough to give up on it :o( thought  obviously I like my answer better :o)

Comment: I also used BigQuery Standard SQL and this worked for me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hi! I have a similar question but I cant get it right, could you help me plz,I have been stuck in this for a lot of time. But it's spark SQL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64123064/spark-sql-lag-result-gets-different-rows-when-i-change-column

Comment: @GordonLinoff but basically I want to make a lag with a condition as in T-SQL

Comment: @JoseMacedo . . . The question that you referenced is a Spark question.  Do you have a T-SQL question?

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, NULL AS lag_result
FROM `project.dataset.table` WHERE start_date != end_date
UNION ALL
SELECT *, LAG(start_date) OVER(ORDER BY start_date)
FROM `project.dataset.table` WHERE start_date = end_date
```

If to apply to sample data in your question - result is

```
Row user_id start_date  end_date    lag_result   
1   1       2019-01-01  2019-02-28  null     
2   3       2019-02-27  2019-02-28  null     
3   4       2019-08-04  2019-09-01  null     
4   2       2019-02-01  2019-02-01  null     
5   5       2019-08-07  2019-08-07  2019-02-01   
6   6       2019-08-27  2019-08-27  2019-08-07
```

Btw, in case if your start_date and end_date are of STRING data type ('27/02/2019') vs. DATE type ('2019-02-27' as it was assumed in above query) - you should use below one

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, NULL AS lag_result
FROM `project.dataset.table` WHERE start_date != end_date
UNION ALL
SELECT *, LAG(start_date) OVER(ORDER BY PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', start_date))
FROM `project.dataset.table` WHERE start_date = end_date
```

with result

```
Row user_id start_date  end_date    lag_result   
1   1   01/01/2019      28/02/2019  null     
2   3   27/02/2019      28/02/2019  null     
3   4   04/08/2019      01/09/2019  null     
4   2   01/02/2019      01/02/2019  null     
5   5   07/08/2019      07/08/2019  01/02/2019   
6   6   27/08/2019      27/08/2019  07/08/2019
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN`

**[SQL FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d361a9195ad0577ecc5eb41fb9d8764a)**

```
SELECT T.*,T1.LAG_Result
FROM TABLE T LEFT JOIN 
(
   SELECT User_Id,LAG(start_date) OVER(ORDER BY start_date) LAG_Result
   FROM TABLE S 
   WHERE start_date = end_date
) T1 ON T.User_Id = T1.User_Id
```